# How to Compare two DataTables and Return another DataTable3 with the rows that only exist in the second DataTable?

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatables, rows, not-exists

I have two DataTables DT1 y DT2. DT1 has two rows and DT2 has three rows. In both DataTables row1 and row 2 have the same columns and values. But row3 not exist in the DT1, it will be my result.

DT1: row1, row2

DT2: row1, row2, row3

Res: DT3: row3

Comment: Well that is nice, did you have a question? Please note that the purpose of Stack Overflow is not to provide tutorials or write your code for you. It is a Q&A site where the best questions and answers deal with specific, delineated programming problems, for which succinct answers are possible. Please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [edit] your question to show at least the approach you think you could follow, where you got stuck and what your specific question is.

Answer (score 0):

```
var good_dt1=dt1.AsEnumerable().Select(t=>new {
   col1=dt1.Field<string>("col1name"),
   ....
});

var good_dt2=dt2.AsEnumerable().Select(t=>new {
  col1=dt2.Field<string>("col1name"),
  ....
});

var result=good_dt2.Except(good_dt1);
//or
var result=good_dt2.Where(d2=>!good_dt1.Any(d1=>d1.col1==d2.col2 && d1.col2==d2.col2 ...));

Stuff result back into a datatable.
```

Comment: Personally, I hate datatables.  They serve no purpose but to create bloat and make things difficult.